# Does apple approve apps without flat design

Tags: ios, iphone, ui-design

Does apple approve the apps with combining Flat + UI gradient effect on icons, screens.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's review process.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apple have no objection with the design of an application screens and icons, but it should meet their guidelines. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/).